# change the number of the iterator in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to conditionally break out of a loop like this..

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 exampleFunction().then(result => {
    res = 0 ? i = 3 : null
 })
}
```

I want `exampleFunction` to run at least 3 times unless it gets the desired result, in which case I want it to stop running.

Comment: well issue you have is it is an asynchronous process so the loop is done running before then() is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exampleFunction` runs asynchronously. The only way to get it working is using `async/await`.

```js
const iterateWithExampleFunction = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log('before', i)

    await exampleFunction().then(result => {
      i = result === 0 ? 3: i;
    });

    console.log('after', i)
  }
};

const exampleFunction = async () => {
  return 0;
}

iterateWithExampleFunction();
```

Comment: `let result = await exampleFunction(); if(result === 0) break;`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a count on the outer scope and then do the async call.

```
let count = 0;

function executeCall() {
  exampleFunction().then(result => {
    // do something with the result
    if (result !== 0 && count !== 3) {
      count += 1;
      executeCall();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `await` the result, than `break`:

```
(async function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   const result =  await exampleFunction();
   if(result === 0) break;
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this gives you some ideas

```
async function poll(f, threshold = 3) {
  if (!threshold) {
    throw new Error("Value not found within configured amount of retries");
  }
  const result = await f();
  if (result >= 0.5) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return await poll(f, threshold - 1);
  }
}

async function task() {
  return Math.random();
}

poll(task).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```